# Sorting on lists of children using common attributes in one method - C#

Tags: c#

Here is the class structure:

```
public class PriorityItem
public class GenePriorityItem : PriorityItem
public class DrugPriorityItem : PriorityItem
public class VariantPriorityItem : PriorityItem
```

I would like to implement a method that can sort a list of any of these items by their common attributes (`PriorityItem` has ~10 attributes).

I tried:

```
protected IEnumerable<PriorityItem> SortResults(string expression, SortDirection direction, IEnumerable<PriorityItem> results)
```

The reason I decided to use `IEnumerable` as opposed to `List` is because I can cast:

```
var list = new List<VariantPriorityItem>()
SortResults(expression, direction, (IEnumerable<PriorityItem>)list)
```

but I can't do this:

```
SortResults(expression, direction, (List<PriorityItem>)list)
```

However all of this doesn't do me any good because I cannot assign the results back to the `List`:

```
list = SortResults(expression, direction, (IEnumerable<PriorityItem>)list)
```

The compiler is telling me it cannot cast down the inheritance tree (which makes sense).

How can I get around this? I would really like to not have to write 4 methods for each of the classes.

Comment: How are you sorting them?  Are the sorting rules volatile?  It's not clear to me why you are going to the trouble of casting everything when you only need to be able to sort `PriorityItem`.

Answer (score 2):

declare method as generic with constraint

```
protected IEnumerable<P> SortResults<P>
(string expression, SortDirection direction, IEnumerable<P> results) 
where P: PriorityItem
```

and than invoke sort as follows

```
list = SortResults(expression, direction, list).ToList()
```

Comment: If he is always going to store the result in a list he could even define the return Type as `List<P>` since a list can be stored in an IEnumerable var

Comment: Can you expand on this? Is there any reason to do this over using OfType<T> as Liam suggested below?

Comment: @pQuestions123, yes. consider such example `SortResults(expression, direction, ((IEnumerable<PriorityItem>))new List<PriorityItem>{new PriorityItem(), new PriorityItem()})` ;`.OfType<VariantPriorityItem>()` will return Empty sequense

Comment: @pQuestions123 additionnaly The bonus over the `OfType` is at least less typing nd a better readability :) => no more cast in the method parameters and no need to call an extension method after that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .OfType< T > and .ToList() operators:

```
list = SortResults(expression, direction, (IEnumerable<PriorityItem>)list)
               .OfType<VariantPriorityItem>()
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work for me in a small test:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SortTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : BaseType
        {
            return list.OrderByDescending(a => a.SortOrder);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Type1> theList = new List<Type1>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                theList.Add(new Type1() { SortOrder = i });
            }

            theList = Sort(theList).ToList();

        }
    }

    public class BaseType { public int SortOrder { get; set; } }
    public class Type1 : BaseType { }
}
```